# Use cv.CaptureFromCAM in Django

Tags: python, django, opencv, python-imaging-library

I use `cv.CaptureFromCAM` in a Django app, but my script block a this command.
Without Django, it works and I can see my webcam turns on.

Here's my script :

```
import cv, Image

def takePhoto():
        """Return a PIL img"""
        print "Taking photo"
        cv_img = cv.QueryFrame( cv.CaptureFromCAM(0) )
        pil_img = Image.fromstring("L", cv.GetSize(cv_img), cv_img.tostring())
        return pil_img
```

If someone know why I can't use a method like `cv.CaptureFromCAM` in Django's scripts ?

PS : I already tried to decompose in several lines...

Comment: There's no error, but the browser always wait for a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved :
I put `cv.CaptureFromCAM` in a var `settings.py` for launch it at website start up.

I access to that var for take a photo, example :

In settings.py:

```
CAM = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
```

In views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import cv, Image

def instantPhoto(request) :
    cv_img = cv.QueryFrame( CAM[0] )
    pil_img = Image.fromstring("RGB", cv.GetSize(cv_img), cv_img.tostring())
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
    pil_img.save(response, "PNG")
    return response
```