# Django app hang-up in cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

Tags: django, opencv

I am trying to take an image from my webcam with a simple Django app. This is my view:

```
def show_home_page(request, template_name="content/homepage.html"):
""" show page """

    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.SaveImage("test.jpg",img) 

    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The code hangs in the line: capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

I tried using the same code in a simple python app and that works:

```
import cv
from Tkinter import *     

def main():
    root = Tk() 
    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.SaveImage("test.jpg",img) 
    cv.ShowImage('Raw', img)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In both cases I run the program in Eclipse 4.2.0, Python 2.7 on Mac OSx mountain Lion. I use opencv-2.4.2

Any clues?

Thanks in advance,
Frans

Comment: I found the solution in an other post [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374626/use-cv-capturefromcam-in-django)